# How can I have Both Splash Activity and Intro Activity?

Tags: java, android

I made a ActivitySplash that worked very well.
Then I made a ActivityIntro that works correctly too.
When I open the app for the first time, I see the Intro and then the ActivityMain.
But for the other times, the app go to the ActivityMain directly.
I Want to have both of them. for the first time ActivityIntro and then ActityMain.
for the other times first ActivitySplash and then ActivityMain.
Would you help me please?

My AndroidManifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bookplus.trace.ir.bookplus">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySplash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ActivityMain" />

        <activity android:name=".ActivityIntro">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My ActivitySplash:

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, ActivityMain.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },2500);
    }
}
```

My ActivityIntro:

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityIntro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.intro_slide1,
                R.layout.intro_slide2,
                R.layout.intro_slide3,
                R.layout.intro_slide4};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityIntro.this, ActivityMain.class));
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling SplashActivity from ActivityIntro ? You should call MainActivity from Splash instead of ActivityIntro.

Comment: yea that way will work but for the first time i dont want to have both

Comment: exactly, ActivityIntro will call directly ActivityMain for first time,and for ither times it will call ActivitySplash. You just need to change method call in ActivityIntro to call ActivitySplash instead of ActivityMain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to show ActivityIntro only once. So you can do this:

Change Manifest to this:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your Splash Activity Use this :

```
private Boolean firstTime = null;



    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (isFirstTime()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,ActivityIntro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 2500);
```

Create a method called isFirstTime like this in your SplashActivity:

```
private boolean isFirstTime(){
    if (firstTime == null){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("first_time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime",true);
        if(firstTime){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime",false);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
    return firstTime;
}
```